Make reboot be an early step in installing GNU/Linux
I install GNU/Linux on old crappy laptops.
One of the problems I have again and again is that the laptop does not boot after installation. Maybe it needs a certain setting in BIOS (think UEFI), maybe it does not support booting on SSD and maybe some completely other problem.
So it annoys me that booting is the very last step of the installation process: I will have to go through the full installation again just to retry the booting.
Instead I would like to install a bare minimum system (think: no graphics, no network, only root as user), and when booting of that works, I want to apt install the rest - preferably from the install medium to avoid downloading.
I would prefer if this could be done with Ubuntu, but if another distro makes this process easy, I am willing to switch.
Is there such a distro? Can it be done with Ubuntu?

If you're setting up Arch Linux, the standard installation guide does exactly that. (Any extra configuration done, like setting up timezones and locales, is only so that you have somewhat reasonable environment after boot, but you could skip everything except configuring fstab and setting the root password.)

@muru Is this guide the normal installation guide? Because I feel I am getting too old to do everything by hand (The guide looks remarkably similar to the SLS guide I followed when I first installed GNU/Linux in 1993). I generally like Ubuntu's installation GUI.

Yes, that's the normal one. There is apparently a tool which automates a lot of it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archinstall but I have never used it and so don't know how well it works

But even using the Ubuntu GUI installer, you could select the minimal installation and choose to skip installing updates, right? That should cut down the installation time considerable


Instead I would like to install a bare minimum system (think: no graphics, no network), and when booting of that works, I want to apt install the rest - preferably from the install medium to avoid downloading.

Yes, that is a very desirable provisioning scheme. If you do like the graphical installer, the debian netinst image is what you want – just in the software selection step, select none but the SSH server.
I do get annoyed by how long it takes me to get to that point, though: user setup, language setup, timezone setup, storage setup, no I don't want to participate in the package popularity contest, yes, I do want you to write the partition table, yes I really want to; at that point, other distro installers are already installing and are asking these questions simply as the files are downloaded and installed in the background.
So I think your solution here is probably:

Make an automated installation recipe that

just flattens the disk,
creates a 1GB UEFI partition,
sets up the rest (or the minimum viable size) as LVM physical volume
creates a single / partition
creates no swap partition at this point
sets up an admin user with pubkey authentication incl the appropriate key
installs an SSH server and not much more
automatically reboots


you put that on a USB stick or on a local server (and boot via network PXE), let the installation run through unattended
you hit the rest with ansible (or just SSH and a shell script) to create swap volumes in your LVM as space is available and as appropriate, installs the desktop environment you want, and any other package

Note that of course "installs an SSH server and not much more" could actually install the full system, if you're doing this unattended and in the background, you won't be too annoyed if booting failed afterwards.
I'm told the debian installer can do such automated installs as well, I simply never did such. I did do it on Fedora with its "anaconda / kickstart files" mechanism, and it works well. A friend of mine just last week set up a rack of servers with Alma Linux that way, and was pleasantly surprised, 6 servers in 2 hours, including learning anaconda-ks. (to be fair, he's been big on provisioning automation before, so don't be discouraged if it takes longer for you.)
